# Excel table show only first occurence

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel table that is sorted alphabetically on row A. In row A there are only 4 different values. What is the easiest way to only show the first occurrence of that value in row A?

I'm trying to avoid using VBA.

Example:

```
A      B       C
Car    Blue    Gasoline
       Red     Diesel
Bike   Red     -
```

Instead of:

```
A      B       C
Car    Blue    Gasoline
Car    Red     Diesel
Bike   Red     -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conditional Formatting to specify that if the value of a cell matches the value of the cell above, pick the the color of the font to be the same as the background color of the cell.  This will make the contents "invisible":

[image]

Comment: Haven't thought about this way yet. Thanks. I'm afraid this will affect performance quite a bit with larger datasets. Any other options?

Also, this would't work in tables with alternating colors.

Comment: @Elmer  I fear you would have to use ***VBA*** to remove the column duplicates.....sorry